# Is it possible to access the event object in an internal AWS lambda extension?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, aws-lambda-extensions

I'm attempting to use an internal lambda extension (aka a wrapper function) to set some environment variables before my lambda function runs, then to use the contents of the `event` object for some additional logic. I'm currently setting those environment variables no problem, but have no idea if accessing the `event` is even possible. Documentation around the limitations of Lambda Extensions is pretty sparse, with only a few examples out there. AWS also uses a bootstrap script to start the function's invoke step, which obfuscates where the `event` object comes from. Does anyone know how I can access the `event` object in the wrapper? Maybe if I return it from the lambda function?? Here's some code snippets because I know you love this stuff

Here is the lambda handler:

```
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        if bool(int(os.environ.get('MY_ENV_VAR', 0))):
            print('Env var is set, do a special little exit')
            return event, context

        print('Doing the normal lambda stuff')

    return 'All done!'
```

Here is the wrapper script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import os

args = sys.argv

os.environ['MY_ENV_VAR'] = 1

# invoke the lambda function
os.system(' '.join(args[1:]))

# this part is what I'm trying to do, but don't know if it's possible

event = AwsLambda.get_event() # this definitely doesn't exist, but you get the point (hopefully)
process_event(event)
```

The wrapper script is packaged as a lambda layer and attached to the lambda function through CDK.

Comment: could you send the event to your wrapper script and then invoke the function, get whatever it returns, then process the event in tandem? I guess I don't understand from your code why you need the event back from the lambda?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/runtimes-extensions-api.html#runtimes-lifecycle-invoke - what kind of extension do you have set up?

Comment: @ASimpleProgrammer I need the event so I can send the request body to an SQS queue depending on the circumstances. I would love to send the event to my wrapper script, do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Can you call the `wrapper_function` from the lambda `handler` rather than the other way round?

```
import wrapper_function

def handler(event, context):
    event = wrapper_function.process_event(event)
    # carry on with the handler
    return 'All done!'
```

Comment: If we cannot access the `event` in the wrapper script, this is our best option

Comment: I think, from the software design perspective, `lambda_handler` is equivalent to `if __name__ == '__main__':` and `event` to `sys.argv`.  It feels quite unnatural to try to squeeze `main()` into the dependency layer.